# Python: Dynamically create objects as they're imported?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I would like to write a python package which will dynamically create importable objects as you attempt to import them.

IE, if you write

```
from importTest import importable
```

It would define `importable` right when you type that.

I thought that maybe I could do this by overriding `__getattribute__` on the module, as shown below, but that didn't work:

```
import sys

def getService(self, name):
    # Ultimately, I want this to query a web service and create objects
    # as you attempt to import them. Defining them all in advance
    # would make for far too heavy a download, as there are hundreds of
    # thousands defined, and users typically use 2-3.

    # For now, just to test if this dynamic import idea works,
    # just return the string with the name.

    return name + '!'

sys.modules[__name__].__getattribute__ = getService
```

Before you scoff and wonder why I would even think that might work, this does work, just, it's not dynamic enough... I need it to not define the attribute until it actually knows the name of what the user is trying to import.

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__].importable = 'importable!'
```

Comment: Do you _need_ to import each service? Why not have a `getService` function that creates services instead (and also caches them)?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - Obviously I don't need to do it. I also don't need to use dictionary literals. I could just make an empty dictionary, then repeatedly add to it. Same end result. Just messy and unpythonic. Similarly, I'd rather if code written by end users were able import classes just like they normally do, instead of having to know about the underlying details and having to use this function which then returns their dynamically generated class. I believe I can do this kind of thing by having the end-user change the `__import__` function, but that would be ugly, too.

Comment: So, you're saying you want to create a module that does _not_ have something like `importable` already defined, but that it you try to import it, it magically comes into existence?

Comment: @BryanOakley - That's correct. The services all exist on a server. They come and go day by day - I don't want to have to constantly update my python module to reflect that. I'd rather if the module just checked the server and got the proper object when the user attempts to import it.

Comment: It seems like you're going to a lot of trouble to solve something that is neatly solved by a factory function.